# Injecting a dependency into a static class

Tags: castle-windsor

What configuration do I need to setup a static property dependency using Windsor container?

I have the following class at the moment and I would like the Logger property to be injected.

```
static class StuffDooer 
{
   static ILogger Logger { get; set; }

   static StuffDooer() { Logger = NullLogger.Instance; }
}
```

Here's my configuration although, this facility seems to automatically find instance properties not problem, the static version is not being set.

```
<facility id="logging"
          type="Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility, Castle.Facilities.Logging"
          loggingApi="nlog"
          customLoggerFactory="Castle.Services.Logging.NLogIntegration.NLogFactory"
          configFile="Configuration/nlog.config" />
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
StuffDooer.Logger = container.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>().GetLogger(typeof(StuffDoer));
```

If you think it's ugly, that is the correct reaction. Statics and and IoC don't mix, same as alcohol and driving.

Comment: LOL Ok, I might rethink my class design instead

Comment: The only difference is that in most places there is a maximum allowed blood alcohol level whilst driving (here it is 0.05%). IOC and statics have a no tolerance approach.